# Detect motion with iPad camera while doing other things

Tags: ipad, video

I have to have a video play-back in a loop, until I detect some motion (activity) with the front camera of iPad.

The video does not need to be recorder or played later, and I do not have to show the current video on the iPad.

Currently they have to tap the screen to stop the video but the customer wants a 'cool' video detection. I am not interested in face detection, just motion.

There are some examples about it ?

thanks,

### EDIT

Well, currently the only workaround that I've found is detecting luminance... Just make an image of every frame (or n frame) and check the luminosity of the image, check another image from another frame and check again, if the variance is enough, something has changed :-)

Just find a good threshold variance and ready to go ...

Of course I would prefere a more robust workaround...